# Increase windows partition size (1 linux, 1 windows)

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I have a linux ext2 partition and a windows 7 partition.
Unfortunately the windows 7 partition is at the end. 
I was thinking about possibly trying to use a linux tool to resize the partitions and take 40GB away from linux.

[image]

Any recommendations on the safest option?

Comment: Everybody talking about GParted and nobody is mentioning CLONEZILLA! Before working with GParted make a full clone of your disk. It *should* work with GParted when you only resize. I deleted a partition and increased windows and the MBR couldn't be found anymore, because the SDAX partition number changed. MAKE A BACKUP!

Answer (score 2):

GParted is fine. Boot from the live CD (either GParted's own, or something like Ubuntu), shrink Linux rootfs, and move & grow the Windows partition.

If GParted for some reason doesn't allow growing C:, it should be enough to just move it leftwards via GParted, and use the pictured diskmgmt.msc to resize (grow) it.

Answer (score 1):

try resize2fs as well. https://access.redhat.com/articles/1196333
But first, ensure a backup of your Linux volume exists and is updated and storage on separate storage.